# Style Get Overriden in xtype button with IconCls in Ext Js 6.0.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs6

I am new in the ext js development. I need a extjs button with icon and text on it. The button behavior (onmouseover , onclick etc) should be same as extjs button.
I am using icon from svg file.

Below are the steps that i am trying, but it does not behave like extjs button:

1. Panel.js :

xtype: 'button',
iconCls: 'svgImage',
minWidth: 20,
maxWidth: 40,
localized: { text: 'localtext' }

Here even if i add the style:'background-color:#eeefea' for the xtype it will disappear the image from the button.

I am thankful, if anyone face the same issue and having solution for the same.

Comment: Please share your code in some fiddle ?

Comment: @Tejas1991 i dont have the code already i shared some pseudocode , i am trying to get by using different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

There are two config options to set button's image:

- **iconCls** - one or more space separated CSS classes to be applied to the icon element
- **icon** - Url to the icon

See my live demo here: https://ext4all.com/post/extjs-6-button-with-svg-icon.html

Comment: Hi khmurach thanks for the reply. I achieved the same by using your suggestion and its gives me result as per the expected.